# Finding a certain link in a webpage, using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraper

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re


user = raw_input('begin here!: ')
base = ("http://1337x.org/search/")
print (base + user)
add_on = "/0/"
total_link = (base + user + add_on)
html_data = urllib2.urlopen(total_link, 'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
announce = soup.find('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/announcelist")})
print announce
```

i am attempting to retrieve a torrent link preferably the first non sponsored link. from a page and then have it print the link. i am rather new at this coding so as much detail as you can give would be perfect! thank you so much for the help!

Comment: It usually helps to explain the problem you are having. How is your code not working for you? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Yeah, more detail would help.  I'm able to find links using steps very similar to yours.  Need help understanding what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your regular expression. You are trying to use the `^` character to negate the regex, but it does not work in your situation. The `^` only negates a set of characters (a set of chars inside `[]`); even in this case it only negates if it is the first char. For example, `[^aeiou]` means "any character *except* `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` and `u`".

When you use `^` *outside* a character set, then it matches the beginning of a line. For example, `^aeiou` matches a line which starts with the `aeiou` string.

So, how would you negate a regex? Well, the best way I see is to use a *negative lookahead*, which is a regex that starts with `(?!` and ends with `)`. For your case, it is pretty easy:

`(?!/announcelist)`

So, replace the `re.compile("^/announcelist")` by `re.compile("(?!/announcelist)")` and it should work - at least worked here :)